# error 1024+1023 with buttons(AS3 Action script 3)

Tags: actionscript-3, button, overriding, action

Here is my code:

```
package  {

import flash.display.SimpleButton;


public class button extends SimpleButton {


    public function button() {

    }

    public function addListeners():void {
        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, downState);
    }
    public function downState(event:MouseEvent):void {
        trace('Test');
    }
}
```

}

The button I made already has correct types(Up, Down, Hit, Over)
What the errors say: 1023 Incompatible override Line 16 Column 19
1024: Overriding a function that is not marked for override Line 16 column 19

Thank you for helping if you want to!

Comment: The error is because your base class (Simple Button) already has a property called `downState` so you can't create a function with the same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `button` class is extending `SimpleButton`, all the public and protected functions and properties from SimpleButton are available in `button`.

The SimpleButton class has a property called `downState`,  so when you try to declare a function called `downState` in the `button` class, you get the error because it's clashing with an existing entity called `downState`.

To fix this error, simply use a name that doesn't exist yet in the scope (`clickHandler` in my example below)

```
package  {

    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent; //add missing imports

    public class button extends SimpleButton {

       public function button(upState:DisplayObject=null, overState:DisplayObject=null, downState:DisplayObject=null, hitTestState:DisplayObject=null){
           //super calls the base class constructor (SimpleButton)
           super(upState, overState, downState, hitTestState);

           //let's automatically add the click listener when the button is created
           addListeners();
       }

        public function addListeners():void {
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
        }

        public function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            trace('Test');
        }
    }
}
```

Also notice a few important other changes:

1. I added the import for the `MouseEvent` class (otherwise you'll get an unknown class error).
2. I'm adding the click listener to `this`, as `button` refers to the class (not the instance of the class) and will give you an unknown property or method error.
3. I've change the constructor (the function whose name matches the class and runs when the object is instantiated/created) to accept all the same parameters as SimpleButton.

Comment: I addressed that in my answer, as well as another error you'll get next

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the addListeners function prior to clicking it?  You could just add the listener when the button is created automatically.

Comment: Not knowning what you're actually trying to do I can't tell you.  Did you pass a hit area into the button when you create it?  If not, it won't fire a click event

Comment: Well, presumably the button should do something when clicked (which requires a click listener). You probably however, don't actually want the click listener in the button class itself, but attached to each individual button instance.   eg:  `var btn:button = new button(..params...); btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);`